# Cannot resolve nullpointerexception

Tags: java, for-loop, nullpointerexception

```
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Personal Contact Assistant!");
    System.out.println("How can I help you?");
    System.out.println("(add) (get) (quit)");
    String option = input.nextLine();
    Contact[] Contacts;
    Contacts = new Contact[500];
    int index = 0;
    boolean finished = false;
    while(finished==false){
        switch (option) {
        case "add": 
            System.out.println("You have selected add.");
            Contact newContact = new Contact();//constructs new contact object called newContact                
            newContact.setNewInfo();//gathers input for newContact
            System.out.println("Contact Will be Saved as:");
            newContact.print();//prints gathered information
            Contacts[index] = newContact;//saves contact to array
            index++;//advances index
            System.out.println("Can I do something else for you? (add) (get) (quit)");
            option = input.nextLine();
            break;
        case "get":
            System.out.println("You have selected get.");
            System.out.println("Enter the contact's first name:");
            String tempName;
            tempName = input.nextLine();
            for(int i=0; i<499; i++){
                System.out.println(":"+i);
                if(Contacts[i].getFirstName().equals(tempName)){
                    System.out.println("Contact Found:");
                    Contacts[i].print();}
            }

            System.out.println("Can I do something else for you? (add) (get) (quit)");
            option = input.nextLine();
            break;
```

These are add and get segments for a contact app I am working on. My Contact class contains methods for setting and getting name, address etc of contacts. I receive no compiler errors but while running the program I get a nullpointerexception error at the for loop. additionally the output will only print 1 number from the System.out.println(":"+i); line (which I added to find out how many loop iterations were actually happening), unless it finds a contact with that first name, in which case it returns the full contact information for each contact and then errors out. I just want it to complete the loop, print ever contact with that first name, and then go back to the main outer loop. Help?

Comment: Please post the *full* stacktrace. This is like saying your car doesn't start and makes a noise without describing which noise it is.

Comment: There isn't a `for`-loop in this code.

Comment: Do you really manually add 500 Contacts?

Comment: Please help yourself and [learn how to debug a Java program](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html)

Comment: @hexafraction not sure how to get the stacktrace from netbeans. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at PersonalContactAssistant.PersonalContactAssistant.main(PersonalContactAssistant.java:48) is the error it gives, line 48 is   for(int i=0; i<499; i++){

Comment: Obviously that line 48 cannot throw an NPE. I suggest you recompile and retest. Clearly you aren't running the code you think you're running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run get() before manually adding 500 contacts, ghis line will throw when i exceeds the number of contacts you've added, since we go to 499 regardless of the number you have added.

```
       if(Contacts[i].getFirstName().equals(tempName)){
```

Even if it finds the one you're looking for, it will continue on through 499.  There are a few ways to fix it.

1. If it's expected that you'll always find it, stop when you find it.
2. Change the loop to:

   for (i = 0; i < index; i++)
3. Use an ArrayList or other collection class, which manages size for you.  Then your search can become:

   for (Contact contact : Contacts) {

Comment: Excellent. I changed the loop to index iterations and now my program works perfectly. Thank you